# How to decrypt using public key?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Can anyone decrypt ciphertext using a public key? I always thought we can only decrypt using a private key. In that case, what does this line in the [RLPx documentation](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/RLPx-Encryption) mean?

`Receiver receives the initiator handshake and decrypts it with its own public key.`

Is the author talking about verifying signatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually a typo, you'd use your private key, not your public key, to establish the secret used for ECIES. File a bug report on the documentation!